# JLabel HTML New Line Issue

Tags: java, html, line, jlabel

I'm trying to call a method from a class called Circle in my project which displays some basic information about the object in a JLabel. For some reason the text won't go to a new line even when I use HTML to try and format it:

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "<html>Type: " + this.getClass().getSimpleName() + "<br>Radius: " + getRadius() + "<br>Area: " + df.format(getArea()) + "<br>Perimeter: </html>" + df.format(getPerimeter());
}
```

I'm trying to display the info with this code:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if(ae.getSource()==btnCalc && x==1){
            //create object
        double R = Double.parseDouble(Txt1.getText());
        Circle circ = new Circle(R);
        lblResult.setText(circ.toString());
        }
```

When I run the program it just returns this:`<html>Type: Circle<br>Radius: 4.0<br>Area: 50.27<br>Perimeter:</html> 25.13`

edit: I tried just setting the text as an exception message instead of calling the method and it didn't work this way either
[image]
edit: Now this happens when I try to run the cylinder-sphere classes, but it doesn't do that when I don't have any html in the toString() method.
[image]

Turns out I was using a DecimalFormat in the last four classes which was what was giving me the exception. Once I got rid of that, the strings formatted nicely using a JTextPane instead of a JtextField.

Comment: Shouldn't your close html tag be at the end of the string, instead of partway through it?

Comment: Even at the end of the string it doesn't format it. It just ends up displaying `<html>Type: Circle<br>Radius: 4.0<br>Area: 50.27<br>Perimeter: 25.13</html>`

Comment: Works fine when I try it: `JLabel lbl = new JLabel("<html>Type: Circle<br>Radius: 4.0<br>Area: 50.27<br>Perimeter: 25.13</html>"); JFrame f = new JFrame(); f.getContentPane().add(lbl); f.pack(); f.setVisible(true);`

Comment: Weird. Is there any way something else in my code could be interfering?

Comment: I think you need to try and reduce your code to a minimal compilable example that exhibits your problem. Then someone may be able to see what the cause is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the image you pasted, it looks like it is a text **INPUT** control (under `Show Info` button), like `JTextField` and not a `JLabel`.

You can use `HTML` content with `JLabel` constructor as well as with its `setText` method too. It works fine.

```
JLabel lbl = new JLabel("<html>Type: Circle<br>Some info<br>More info</html>")

JLabel lbl2 = new JLabel();
lbl2.setText("<html>Type: Circle<br>Some info<br>More info</html>")
```

But if you want to have an **INPUT** control (as in your image), you can not use `HTML` with `JTextField`. You have to use `JTextPane` for this.

```
JTextPane txt = new JTextPane();
txt.setContentType("text/html");
txt.setText("<html>Type: Circle<br>Some info<br>More info</html>");
```